# Python - Separating a list into list of lists

Tags: python, for-loop, nested-lists, python-re

First time asking a question so apologize for any mistakes.

I'm trying to create a script in Python that can read all satellite imagery files from a folder, only pick the ones that are imagery, then sort those by sensor, and finally by different scene (a scene is a specific set of satellite imagery for a given location and datetime).

So far I've used glob to take the images (each satellite imagery is composed by 8-12 bands, so you have 8-12 images per scene), then sort them by sensor using a for loop to look for names in the naming folder.

Last step is to go by each sensor list and separate them by scenes, looking by name, so I can then open them with rasterio.

So my code looks like this so far (abbreviated form):

```
# Pick the images I want

sat_bands = glob(path, recursive = True)
sat_bands.sort()

# Set each one according to respective satellite

LC08_list = []
... # Create an empty list for each sensor

for i in sat_bands:
    if "LC08" in i:
        LC08_list.append(i)
    ...  # Do if statements for each sensor
```

And I end up with a list containing the path for every satellite imagery bands for the specific sensor.
In this example, I'm using 2 Landsat-8 imagery, with 8 bands each.

The naming scheme looks something like this:

```
'Dados/Sat_Img\\LC08_L2SP_203033_20200819_20200904_02_T1\\LC08_L2SP_203033_20200819_20200904_02_T1_ST_B10.TIF'
'Dados/Sat_Img\\LC08_L2SP_203033_20200819_20200904_02_T1\\LC08_L2SP_203033_20200819_20200904_02_T1_SR_B3.TIF'
'Dados/Sat_Img\\LC08_L2SP_203033_20201123_20210315_02_T1\\LC08_L2SP_203033_20201123_20210315_02_T1_SR_B7.TIF'
```

The first two belong to the same scene (they are in the same subfolder and the name is almost the same, except for the band number), and the last one is from a different scene.

Using regular expressions, I know that if I use `".*_[STR]+?"` I distinguish between each scene, while ignoring the _Band termination.
I figured I could use some sort of for loop with if statements to sort each scene into a list of lists, but I'm having trouble indexing each scene as a nested list.
Here's what my most successful attempt looks like:

Created two variables, y and z, to loop around the list, and created and empty list to receive the new nested lists.

```
z = 0
y = 0
L8_sub = list()
L8_ = list()
```

Then tried the for loop:

```
for z in range(len(LC08_list)):

    if re.findall(".*_[STR]+?", LC08_list[z]) == re.findall(".*_[STR]+?", LC08_list[y]):

        L8_.append(LC08_list[z])

    else:
        y = z  # So y catches up to the last  if true
        L8_sub.append(LC08_list[z]) # So the "False" statment gets carried over
        L8_.append(LC08_list[z])
    
    L8_.append(L8_sub)  # So I append each list of scenes to the main List for each sensor
```

This loop creates an L8_ list of 16 lists (the number of files I have inside LC08 list), each with 8 strings (8 bands, so it is constraining a specific scene). The weird thing is that is actually capturing scene 2, and not scene 1...

```
L8_ = [[scene2_B1, scene2_B2, scene2_B3 ... scene2_B10], ['scene2_B1, scene2_B2, scene2_B3 ... scene2_B10], ...]
```

The expected result should be like

```
L8_ = [[scene 1_B1, scene 1_B2, ...], [scene 2_B1, scene 2_B2, ...]]
```

i.e, L8_ containing 2 lists of 8 strings each, since I have 2 scenes, with 8 bands each.

I also tried fiddling around with a third variable, <x>, so I could use it to append L8_sub to specific list index in L8, but I kept getting "out of range index" errors.

I appreciate any feedback you can give!

I apologize if the question is long, but I've been on this site for quite a while and I know how difficult it is to understand a question without any context or example code.

Comment: at first glance one issue is that you append `L8_sub` to the `L8_` list multiple times without creating a new one.

Comment: @njzk2 What do you mean by "without creating a new one"? Do you think my for loop is running z 16 times, appending to L8_sub 16 times, and appending to L8_ 16 times all over? It runs fairly quick, so I haven't thought about that possibility yet...